# How to get number of elements inside a multidimensional array for each element in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this which stores the following information

```
$array = array
(
  0 => Array
    (
      0=>'some value'
      1=>'some value'
      2=>'some value'
    )
    1 => Array
    (
      0=>'some value'
      1=>'some value'
      2=>'some value'
      3=>'some value'
      4=>'somevalue'
    )
    2 => Array
    (
      0=>'some value'
      1=>'some value'
      2=>'some value'
      3=>'some value'
      4=>'somevalue'
      5=>'somevalue'
    )
)
```

I need to get count for each element like for 0 there are total **3 elements**, and for 1 there are total **5 elements** and for 2 **six element** how can i get
such result

Comment: Use `count` function for each subarray.

Comment: `foreach()` loop, `count()`

Answer (score 3):

You can [map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) the [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function over your array.

```
$counts = array_map('count', $array);
```

The result will be an array that corresponds to your original array, with the number of elements in each sub-array as its values.

(So, for the example in your question, `$counts` would be set to `[3, 5, 6]`.)